# Android NumberFormatException

Tags: android

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1437061569000"
```

Full error [here](http://pastebin.com/6pJBycfz).

I have checked whether the string is null, applied the trim() and replace() methods to remove any non integer characters.

The line of the error (42) is the line on which the parseInt method is ran on the string.

Code here:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... college) {
    String data_url = "......";
    int lastUpdateTimestamp;
    try {
        String data = DownloadText(data_url).trim().replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
        Log.e("doinback", data);
        if (data == null) { Log.e("doinback", "ITS NULL"); }
        lastUpdateTimestamp = Integer.parseInt(data);
        res = "done";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        res = "ERROR";
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: please, learn java's basics ... `int` cannot be greater than `Integer.MAX` (2^31 − 1) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number is too large. The maximum value an int can have is 2^31 - 1. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

> java.lang.Integer
>
> **MAX_VALUE**
>
> `public static final int MAX_VALUE`
>
> A constant holding the maximum value an `int` can have, 2^31-1.

2^31 - 1 = 2 147 483 647

Answer (score 3):

### Java Int

> Int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer.
>
> Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31)
>
> Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1)

`1.437.061.569.000` is way, way bigger than the maximum value.

You need to use a **long** variable.

### Java Long

> Long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.
>
> Minimum value is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.(-2^63)
>
> Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). (2^63 -1)

Please read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm

Answer (score 1):

**Why don't you use `long` instead?**

---

The `NumberFormatException` was thrown because of the `Integer` value was overlimit. The limit for `Integer` is from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

If you want to use this number (`1437061569000`) as your `lastUpdateTimestamp` variable, you can convert it to `long`, which has bigger limit than `Integer`, i.e. from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.